# jQuery $.ajax equivalent for Ajax.updater

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to find the equivalent for this Ajax function in using jQuery
this is the ajax code that i want to convert over.

```
new Ajax.Updater('folder', 'ajax/get_folders.php', {
parameters: { category: #$F('category'), office: #$F('office') }
```

This is what I have so far.

```
$.ajax({
url:'ajax/get_folders.php',
data: { category: $('#category').val(), office: $('#office').val() }
});
```

Not sure what to do with the item 'folder' in the original ajax call. That updates the options in a select on a form for the website. This is the only part of the code that has stumped me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `success` callback and update the contents of the corresponding DOM element:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/get_folders.php',
    data: { category: $('#category').val(), office: $('#office').val() },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#folder').html(result);
    }
});
```

or simply use the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
var parameters = { 
    category: $('#category').val(), 
    office: $('#office').val() 
};
$('#folder').load('ajax/get_folders.php', parameters);
```

Comment: It works awesome thank you so much. I wasn't so sure about the success option for jQuery but i felt like that had something to do with what i was looking for. thanks again